# shell echo not following the order sequence

Tags: shell, unix

I have a function

```
foo_bar()
{
  echo "foo_bar"
  read -p "enter option" option
  echo $option
}


option=$(foo_bar)
echo $option
```

It returns

```
enter option
and then in one line
foo_bar [option]
```

What I am expecting is the execution follows the order I write it..
i.e like

```
foo_bar
enter option

[option]
```

How do i do this in shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are capturing the output of `foo_bar` in the variable `option`.  That output includes the text that foo_bar echos.  (That is, you are assigning the string `foo_bar\n$option` to the variable `option`, and echo is replacing the newline with a space) However, `read -p` prints its prompt to stderr.  If you want "foo_bar" to print to the same place that read prints its prompt, do so explicitly:

```
foo_bar()
{
  echo "foo_bar" >&2
  read -p "enter option" option
  echo $option
}


option=$(foo_bar)
echo $option
```

Answer (score 1):

add an echo before:

```
option=$(foo_bar)
```

so it becomes:

```
foo_bar()
{
  echo "foo_bar"
  read -p "enter option" option
  echo $option
}

echo
option=$(foo_bar)
echo $option
```